# ASPX label with text as an anchor tag with encoded tags not working

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a label with its text set dynamically either as an anchor tag or simple text based on the result

```
`label.Text = result;`
```

If the result is an anchor tag as below

```
 <a  title="TestLink" class="lnk"  href="#" onclick="javascript:OpenInNewWindow('/test1/test.html');">Tests</a>
```

The link is displayed in the site as

```
&lt;a  title="TestLink" class="lnk"  href="#" onclick="javascript:OpenInNewWindow('/test1/test.html');"&gt;Tests&lt;/a&gt;
```

instead of a link.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but from your question I'm not quite sure what the problem is. Maybe reword it or format it differently. Not trying to be difficult, promise :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had included the exact value of `result`, it would have been better. But looking at your output, I guess you are getting html encoded text in the `result` (like `&lt;a  title="TestLink" class="lnk"  href="#" onclick="javascript:OpenInNewWindow('/test1/test.html');"&gt;Tests&lt;/a&gt;`) which is causing this behavior.

So you can try following:

```
label.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(result);
```

Note that MSDN article talks about a security risk of displaying HTML inside label. Please read details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.text(v=vs.110).aspx